# Is an in-place upgrade of HPE storage controllers non-destructive?

Tags: raid, storage, windows-server-2019, hpe

I've taken over a relatively small shop and would like to upgrade a host that's in production. Looking to get a more definitive answer to the title and would appreciate some firsthand experience.

The host in question is a DL380 G10 (1 socket populated, another cpu on order) using a P408i-a with bay 3 populated by 8 SAS drives. Two raid 6 logical arrays are configured. One is the host OS and the other is data. Restorative backups are in place and tested.

In order to expand storage on this host we have tentatively planned to add another 8 drives (881457-B21) via Box1/2 Cage/Backplane (826691-B21), and SAS Expander w/ Cables (870549-B21). We also ordered a P816i-a (804338-B21) as a spare controller or possible in-place upgrade for this effort.

New Controller upgrade path:

- Confirm backups, bitlocker recovery info
- Install latest Smart Array driver
- Replace P408i-a with P816i-a
- Connect battery to P816i-a
- *New controller pulls array configuration from the drives?
- *Unsure what to expect at first boot with new controller
- Confirm functionality with previously configured arrays
- Install new backplane and drives
- Configure new array and cache settings

Existing controller upgrade path:

- Confirm backups, bitlocker recovery info
- Install new backplane and drives
- Install SAS Expander w/ Cables
- Connect Expander to P408i-a
- Configure new array

There is a spare DL380 that we could use to replicate either upgrade path, but would appreciate some input regarding the feasibility of either plan being non-destructive. If you know of HPE documentation that speaks to previously configured controller upgrades and the configuration steps it would be much appreciated.

Thanks all